# get a specific value from arraylist element java

Tags: java, arraylist, element

i have an arraylist where it has certain number of elements, each consisting of two values (day,cents)
`company.getAnnouncements().get(0)`

The above code will retrieve the first element in the arraylist, but i only want the cents component of that element.
How would you do this??

```
public class Announcement implements Event {
private int day ;
private String statement;
    public Announcement(int day, String statement) {
            this.day = day;
            this.statement = statement;
    }

    @Override
    public String printEvent() {

        return statement;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return day;
    }


}
```

This is the Announcement class i have and Dividend extends it

```
public class Dividend extends Announcement {

    private int cents;

        public Dividend(int day, int cents) {
            super(day,"");
            this.cents=cents;       

        }


        public double getCents() {
        return (double) (cents)/100;
        }

        public void setCents(int cents) {
            this.cents = cents;
        }


        @Override
        public String printEvent() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return "Dividend of " + getCents() + " per share"  ;
        }

    }`
```

And the Company Class

```
    public class Company implements Event {

private String name;
private String code;
private int currShares;
private double previousPrice;
private ArrayList <Dividend> dividends;
private ArrayList <Announcement> announcements;
private ArrayList <Trade> trades;

public Company(String code, String name, int currShares,
        double previousPrice) {
    this.name = name;
    this.code = code;
    this.setCurrShares(currShares);
    this.previousPrice = previousPrice;
    this.trades = new ArrayList <Trade> ();
     this.dividends = new ArrayList <Dividend> ();
     this.announcements = new ArrayList <Announcement> ();
}

public void addDividend(int day , int cents){
    dividends.add(new Dividend(day, cents));

 }

public void addAnnouncement(int day , String statement){
    announcements.add(new Announcement(day, statement));

}

public void addTrade(int day , int sharesTraded , double pricePerShare){
    trades.add(new Trade(day, sharesTraded, pricePerShare));

}


public String printEvent() {

    return "Printed!!";
}

public String getCode() {   
    return code;
}

public ArrayList<Dividend> getDividends() {
    return dividends;
}

public void setDividends(ArrayList<Dividend> dividends) {
    this.dividends = dividends;
}

public ArrayList<Announcement> getAnnouncements() {
    return announcements;
}

public void setAnnouncements(ArrayList<Announcement> announcements) {
    this.announcements = announcements;
}

public ArrayList<Trade> getTrades() {
    return trades;
}

public void setTrades(ArrayList<Trade> trades) {
    this.trades = trades;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void addAnnouncement(int day, int cent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    announcements.add(new Dividend(day,cent));
}

public int getCurrShares() {
    return currShares;
}

public void setCurrShares(int currShares) {
    this.currShares = currShares;
}


}
```

Comment: Based on what you've provided, I would do that through a complicated set of reflection and probabilistic field name matching. But it would be easier if you could show us what exactly you're getting out of the list?

Comment: is there a way i can add more information for my question??

Comment: i need to retrieve the information about a "Dividend" class that extends "Announcement" class. Dividend class has day and cents as its attributes and extends Announcement class which has day and statement as attributes.

Comment: Would it be preferable if i just closed this question and started a new one with the actual classes in it????

Comment: Use the "edit" button right of the "share" button (under the tags: java, arraylist, etc) to edit the body of your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just access it as you would with any other getter (this is assuming, `Announcement` has a `getCents` method):

```
int cents = company.getAnnouncements().get(0).getCents();
```

Or, if you don't have a `getCents` method (which, by the way, you should!):

```
int cents = company.getAnnouncements().get(0).cents;
```

I assumed `int` as the type of `cents`, you would have to provide us with what `Announcement` looks like to tell for sure, how you'd access it.

**Update**

After your edit, it seems as if you don't want `getAnnouncements` but rather `getDividends`. That would look somewhat like this:

```
double cents = company.getDividends().get(0).getCents();
```

Comment: Thankyou, I added more code if youd like to take a look.

Comment: @30088121 It seems like `company` doesn't have a `getAnnouncements` method. And even if it did, why don't you take the dividends instead of the announcements from `company` if that seems to be what you wanted?

Comment: Hey @germi Sorry mate, i hadnt added the whole company class because its for an assignment and my teacher wouldnt really appreciate me having the whole assignment up there :/

Comment: but i added it all there now

Comment: @30088121 Added a bit to the answer with regards to your update.

Answer (score 0):

I belive `company.getAnnouncements()` returns you the `list`, and by `company.getAnnouncements().get(0)` you get to the `bean` object.

There must a `getCents()` or something in the `bean` class, and you final code should look like `company.getAnnouncements().get(0).getCents()`

or if the `cents` is an attribute in the bean class, the you can also do `company.getAnnouncements().get(0).cent`

Comment: Thankyou, I added more code if youd like to take a look.

Answer (score -1):

You need to know the type of the value object in order to know how to access it.

If its another arraylist you would do:

> int cents = company.getAnnouncements().get(0).get(1);

Comment: Thankyou, I added more code if youd like to take a look.